# Launching an ICO with parity

Tags: parity, ico, parity-wallet

I am trying to understand cryptocurrencies and ICOs in general.  I can find a lot of examples of using the Parity client to *participate* in ICOs but not a lot of examples on how to launch/create an ICO using Parity.

From what I understand, once you have deployed and registered a token.  You need an ICO smart contract (aka. a crowdsale smart contract? https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/tree/master/contracts/crowdsale) which are essentially the rules as to how an ICO is run.

So, if I register and deploy a token, do I then need to deploy a crowdsale smart contract using Parity.  Am I understanding this correctly?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No, You are confusing yourself. The contract defines your Token attributes such as name, symbol and decimals. Once you're compiled your contract you have to deploy it in the main ethereum blockchain using any multising wallet such as Mist, Parity and Ethereum wallet or using truffle framework. You can find the complete Token solidity code in [Ethereum Website](https://ethereum.org/token). There is no way to register your token name and symbol. Anyone can create a token contract with same name and symbol. Only your contract address helps us to identify the genuine one.

Comment: So what are the Token Registry and Token Deploy options in Parity client, are they essentially a way of easily creating a contract?

Comment: If you register your token in parity Token Registry by paying a fee of 0.005ETH then by default they will display ur token details in parity wallets. If you use parity deploy function, they will deploy a token contract for you and it will contain only limited functions. So if you wish to add any additional functionalities, compile token contract on your own and deploy it using deploy contract section in parity wallet

Comment: so you if you wanted to create a crowdsale, you would compile a crowdsale contract and deploy that?

Comment: Yes  your correct